# Indexing vs Slicing of empty strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, indexing, slice

I noticed the following *weird* behavior:

```
>> str_ = ''  # empty string
>> str_[0:]
''
>> str_[0]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

**Is there some kind of reasoning for this?**

---

My interpretation of the current return value of **slicing** is:

> *from position X onwards (and up until Y with a step of Z) there is `''` to be found.*

which clearly means that there are no characters in the specified interval and thus the string is smaller than (X+1) characters long.

Similarly, one could treat **indexing** the same way and say:

> *at position X of string there is `''` to be found.*

which would also clearly mean that there is nothing there to be found.

but that is not the case. Indexing is treated differently and I am wondering why.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Nice find. Somehow my google-fu didn't not return it. Thanks!